# ODE: continuous dependence on parameters

Tags: reference-request, ordinary-differential-equations

Is it true that the solutions of the problem:
$$\begin{cases} \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} s} [s^{2-2/N} u^\prime (s)] + \frac{\lambda}{c_N^2}\ u(s)=0 \\
u(\bar{s})=1\\ u^\prime (\bar{s})=-\frac{\lambda}{c_N^2}\ \bar{s}^{2/N-1}\end{cases}$$
(here $N\in \mathbb{N}$, $N\geq 2$ and $c_N>0$ is a suitable constant) depend continuously, or even smoothly, on both parameters $\lambda$ and $\bar{s}$?

Where can I learn about continuous or smooth dependence for this kind of problems?